# Have BOTH an onLongPress menu and select-copy text on aTextview item?

Tags: android

My App contains a RecyclerView with TextView items. On each TextView item I have defined a few functionalities, like sharing the text to another App.

How can I combine both onLongPress or onCreateContextMenu with (enabling) select-and-copy text? It is OK to enable the select-and-copy text from the context menu.

Of course I could use the for **selecting text**. But that **conflicts** with the long press (context) menu on the textview item.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/pwTextView"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"   <== mandatory
    android:focusable="true"          <== optionally
    android:longClickable="true" />   <== optionally
```

Of course I would like to have the context menu back after select-copying the text.

Is this functionality realistic? Yes. For the app this is essential. I have seen it in other apps as well ;-)

Comment: You can do one thing, setup onLongPress of whole itemview. then in that use view to get specific textviews and put action on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution helps me for most situations.

I want text to be either selectable (for copy and paste) or want other gestures to work.

Initially setting the gestures on the text field:

- Set textIsSelectable to false, either in the layout file or programmatically.
- Set an onTouchListener on the textview with your Gestures.
- Allow one of the gestures to switch to textSelection mode. See below.

How to set textSelection programmatically?

- Set the textIsSelectable, focusable, longPressable to true
- Set the onTouchListener to null.
- Install a clickListener on the textview to allow you switch back to the original TouchListener.

1) Install your GestureHandler:

```
// Create your Touch Listener  
onTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(mCtx, this);
view.setOnTouchListener( onTouchListener);
```

2) Switch to textselction modus:

```
// Create your popup with an menu option to switch to textselection modus:
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mCtx, view);
popup.inflate(R.menu.text_options_menu);
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case ...
            case R.id.text_textisselectable:
                view.setOnTouchListener(null);
                ((TextView)view).setTextIsSelectable( true);
                ((TextView)view).setFocusable( true);
                ((TextView)view).setLongClickable( true);
                // Install a click listener to switch back to the previous Touch Listener
                ((TextView)view).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PopupMenu popupx = new PopupMenu(mCtx, view);
                        popupx.inflate(R.menu.selecttext_back_menu);
                        popupx.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                ((TextView)view).setTextIsSelectable( false);
                                ((TextView)view).setFocusable( false);
                                ((TextView)view).setLongClickable( false);
                                view.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
                                return true;
                            }});
                            popupx.show();
                        }
                    });
                break;
```